# airflow webserver command fails with {filesystemcache.py:224} ERROR - Operation not permitted

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, airflow

- I am installing airflow on a Cent OS 7. I have configured airflow db init and checked the status of the nginx server as well its working fine. But when I run the airflow webserver command I am getting the below mentioned error*`[2021-03-22 14:59:30 +0000] [9019] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9019 [2021-03-22 14:59:32,548] {filesystemcache.py:224} ERROR - set key '\x1b[01m__wz_cache_count\x1b[22m' -> [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/tmpdwzf56wm.__wz_cache' -> '/tmp/2029240f6d1128be89ddc32729463129'`

Comment: I am too facing the issue with ubuntu local user

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and just resolved it by setting `PrivateTmp=true` in the systemd service script of airflow-webserver.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/systemd/airflow-webserver.service#L32

Comment: Is there a way to do this without systemd or setup systemd without root permissions?

Comment: @manthang Can you please provide the location of "airflow-webserver.service" in windows ?