# Airflow webserver error in WSL: PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following this [guide](https://insaid.medium.com/setting-up-apache-airflow-in-windows-using-wsl-8e0a87cd4945) to install Airflow in my Windows machine.

However, in the step to start Airflow webserver I get his error:

```
=================================================================
[2021-10-07 22:51:25 -0300] [7468] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
    super().run()
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 198, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 137, in start
    self.pidfile.create(self.pid)
  File "/home/thadeu/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/pidfile.py", line 45, in create
    os.chmod(self.fname, 420)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/f/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid'
```

I couldn't find a solution in other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748803/airflow-webserver-command-fails-with-filesystemcache-py224-error-operation).

My WSL user has root privileges running Ubunto 20.04

Comment: try $ sudo chmod goua+rwx paht_your_airflow_home . Works for me

Comment: Or try read this https://insaid.medium.com/setting-up-apache-airflow-in-windows-using-wsl-8e0a87cd4945#08cd and do in root user, works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should have airflow folders in Linux not in windows filesystem. The windows filesystem has no group permissions so chmod fails. Simply make sure that airflow homedir is the Linux FS  in WSL not volume mounted from windows

You can do it by setting AIRFLOW_HOME variable

Comment: I set AIRFLOW_HOME in /mnt/f/airflow .

Comment: There was a error when I created the virtualenv in /mnt/f/airflow and the solution was to create the vitualenv in /home/<user>